# TypeError: ArrayType(DoubleType,true) can not accept object u'..'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I cannot create a DataFrame because of `coordinates`. This field does not fit the schema type `ArrayType(DoubleType())`.

```
my_schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField('alarm_id', StringType()),
            StructField('coordinates',ArrayType(DoubleType()))
        ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, my_schema)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: ArrayType(DoubleType,true) can not accept object u'[[[1.7594273000000102, 41.82814869999999], [1.7594281999999908, 41.828104700000004]]]' in type <type 'unicode'>
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: What does `rows` look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that your data is type of string.

You can use the `ast` lib in order to make it a list.

```
import ast

rows = '[[[1.7594273000000102, 41.82814869999999], [1.7594281999999908, 41.828104700000004]]]'

rows_li = ast.literal_eval(rows)
```

More on [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: But then I'll have `ArrayType(StringType())` instead of `ArrayType(DoubleType())`.

Comment: @Markus, why? It will convert into float.